when using ffmpeg through batch files how can i exclude files/folders
I have a batch file set to compress all of my files due to my previous lack of knowledge and full harddrive. However, since it is running from the base of the harddrive it seems to keep catching my recycle bin even though it is a hidden folder. I really don't want it to since each file takes about a day to process.
here is the line that compresses the files
@echo off
set "_x=compressed"
for /r %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -map 0:v -vcodec libx265 -crf 24 -map 0:a "%%~dpni%_x%.mp4"


@echo off

setlocal
cd /d "c:\"

set "_x=compressed"
set "_sts=-hide_banner -v error -stats"

set "_ff_bin=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_flag=-map 0:v -vcodec libx265 -x265-params log-level=error:parameter1=value:parameter2=value -crf 24 -map 0:a?"

for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%G in =;(` 
    2^>nul where /r . *.mov *.mp4 *.mkv ^| find /v /i "c:\$recycle.bin" ^| find /v /i "c:\OneDrive" ^| find /v /i "C:\Windows" ^| find /v /i "C:\Program"
   `);= do title <nul & title "%%~nxG" & if not exist "%%~dpnG%_x%.mp4" 2>&1 =;( echo/"%%~fG" & 0<con: "%_ff_bin%" -i "%%~fG" %_sts% %_flag% "%%~dpnG%_x%.mp4"
        );= 
        
timeout -1 | =;( endlocal & echo/iS dOnE!.. );=


You can try using the recursive where command (/R for recursive search) to locate your files, and then pipe the results (|) to find to exclude (/V for inverted match) certain folders from the search.

You can also expand the filtering in the output resulting from the filters within the for /f loop by using additional find commands and conditionally executing the command with && (run ...) in:
for .. ( ... ) do (echo/%%~dpnG" | find /v /i "...) && ( run..:

@echo off

setlocal
cd /d "c:\"

set "_x=compressed"
set "_sts=-hide_banner -v error -stats"

set "_ff_bin=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_flag=-map 0:v -vcodec libx265 -x265-params log-level=error:parameter1=value:parameter2=value -crf 24 -map 0:a?"

for /f usebackq^ ^delims^= %%G in =;(` 
    2^>nul where /r . *.mov *.mp4 *.mkv ^| find /v /i "c:\$recycle.bin" ^| find /v /i "c:\OneDrive" ^| find /v /i "C:\Windows" ^| find /v /i "C:\Program"
   `);= do =;( echo/%%~dpnG" | find /v /i "c:\Recovery" | find /v /i "c:\System Volume" | find /v /i "C:\Windows" | find /v /i "C:\XboxGames" );= && =;(
         if not exist "%%~dpnG%_x%.mp4" 2>&1 =;( echo/"%%~fG" & 0<con: echo/"%_ff_bin%" -i "%%~fG" %_sts% %_flag% "%%~dpnG%_x%.mp4" 
        );=  
    );=
    
timeout -1 | =;( endlocal & echo/iS dOnE!.. );=


Additional resources:

Set /?

For /?

For /F /?

Where /?

Find /?

If() Else If() Else() /?

Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Commands Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, etc.

Q: FFmpeg prevent output Stream map '0:a:0' matches no streams

Refer: Set "_flag=... -map 0:a?"


Q: FFmpeg libx265 prevent output x265 [info]:

Refer: Set "_flag=... -x265-params log-level ..."


How does the Windows Command Interpreter [cmd.exe] Parse Scripts


